# Guava Supplier : transforming a collection with each element's own function

Tags: java, guava

Let's say I have a Node class that has a Function as an instance variable.

```
public class Node {
    private Function<Node, Double> function;
    ...
```

I have a List of these Nodes:

```
List<Node> nodes = Lists.newLinkedList();
nodes.add(new Node(someFunction));
nodes.add(new Node(someOtherFunction));
```

I can do this:

```
public Collection<Double> getValues() {
    SomeFunction f = new SomeFunction(); 
    return Collections2.transform(nodes, f);
}
```

Sure enough, transform iterates over the nodes List and applies the function f to each element like mapcar.

What I'm trying to do is to have transform use the function that each node element has.

So I though that the Supplier would help.

```
class NodeSupplier implements Supplier<Node> {
    Iterator<Node> iterator;

    NodeSupplier(Iterable p) {
        iterator = Iterators.cycle(p);
    }

    @Override
    public Node get() {
        return iterator.next();
    }
}
```

Then a Function to get a Node.

```
class SupplierGetter implements Function<Supplier<Node>, Node> {
    @Override
    public Node apply(Supplier<Node> from) {
        return from.get();
    }
}
```

Then compose them:

```
FunctionGetter fg = new FunctionGetter();
NodeSupplier sup = new NodeSupplier(this); // the this class is Iterable
Supplier<Function<Node, Double>> supplier = Suppliers.compose(fg, sup);
```

But then it gives me a type mismatch when I try to use it:

```
Collections2.transform(nodes, supplier);
```

it wants suppler.get() which is called once.

```
Collections2.transform(nodes, supplier.get());
```

**Is there an easier way?**

I saw mention of

```
Suppliers.supplierFunction()
```

but that seem s to not exist in verison r09.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused by what you're trying to do... `Supplier` doesn't seem useful here. Each `Node` has its own `Function`. You want to transform a collection of `Node`s by applying each `Node`'s `Function` to itself. So why not just give the `Node` class some method:

```
// may want a better name
public Double applyFunction() {
  return function.apply(this);
}
```

Then you'd just `transform` using a `Function` like this:

```
public Double apply(Node node) {
  return node.applyFunction();
}
```

Comment: That is what I was doing. (I called it getValue() rather than applyFunction()). Unfortunately in relation to the other classes this broke 2 modeling fiats. So I was looking for help elsewhere. The Supplier isn't a help here.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the fact that I also have my doubts about what you are trying to do, the following should achieve what you are asking for:

```
class Node {
    private Function<Node, Double> function;

    private static Function<Node,Double> applyFunction = new Function<Node,Double>() {
        @Override
        public Double apply(final Node input) {
            return input.function.apply(input);
        }
    };

    public static Iterable<Double> transform(final Iterable<Node> nodes) {
        return Iterables.transform(nodes, applyFunction);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, because you seriously confused me by dragging Supplier into this.

Comment: It is essentially the same as ColinD's reply, just a bit more explicit.

Comment: Thank you for having doubts. That helped. I just didn't know how to ask a question about the Supplier without dragging the Supplier into the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third way to do this without modifying the Node class, if we suppose that `Node` exposes its function through a public getter.

**Using an anonymous class :**

```
public Collection<Double> getValues() {
    return Collections2.transform(nodes, new Function<Node, Double>() {
        @Override public Double apply(Node node) {
            return node.getFunction().apply(node);
        }
    });
}
```

**Using the enum singleton pattern** (which I prefer, since it's clearer) **:**

```
public Collection<Double> getValues() {
    return Collections2.transform(nodes, ApplyNodeFunction.INSTANCE);
}

/**
 * A {@link Function} that applies the {@link Node}'s own function on itself.
 */
private enum ApplyNodeFunction implements Function<Node, Double> {
    INSTANCE;

    @Override public Double apply(Node node) {
        return node.getFunction().apply(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to my question was this phrase: "So I thought that the Supplier would help." The answer is that it doesn't. I was trying to find a use for it - outside of Map creation which seems to be its main use. There was that one Suppliers method I mentioned but it seems to be MIA. Perhaps this could be an RFI for tranform be overloaded to take an Iterable as the second parameter

Comment: Supplier has some uses (such as lazily constructing a singleton when combined with Suppliers.memoize()), but in your case it would complicate things unnecessarily. You got a type mismatch because you were attempting to pass a Supplier to the transform() method whose argument is supposed to be a Function. Suppliers.compose() doesn't do what you want: it returns a new Supplier, not a Function. What you wanted was Suppliers.supplierFunction(), which does seem to exist in r09: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html (last function)

Comment: Also, the resulting Function would have been stateful, which is dangerous. Each call to "apply()" would change the function's state (by selecting the next element in the Iterable).